# getFragmentManager() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app targets API 8 and higher and uses ActionbarSherlock. The `Activity` extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`. My fragment adapter for the viewpager is as follows:

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ...
    }

  @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);

        FragmentManager manager = ((ListFragment) object).getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment) object);
        trans.commit();
    }
}
```

The `destroyItem` is used to remove a page of a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. This works fine the first time, maybe the first two times a page is deleted. But at some point of continued page deletion, the `manager` returns null and the app crashes on the `manager.beginTransaction()` line.

I can't seem to figure out why this is...

Comment: This could be due to the super.destroyItem(....); being called before your manager call. It's possible that ((ListFragment) (object)) has some of it's properties being destroyed before your call. Essentially race conditions, which would explain the intermittent nature. Try moving the call to super.destroy... after your code.

Comment: Also in the future please add stack trace when you have crash issues.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. It turns out the `ListFragment` passed into the `destroyItem` has its `FragmentManager == null` because I'm not properly deleting nulled `WeakReference` items in the List.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, some days ago I could find my error.

The solution is simple:

Just create a new Bundle variable as a global variable

```
Bundle datosGuardados;
```

to store the data of savedInstanceState

```
datosGuardados = savedInstanceState;
```

and finally just check if it is null before than using any getFragmentManager

```
if (datosGuardados != null) infoF = (InformacionFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.posicionamiento_layout);
```